# JavaScript innerHtml not changing to php session

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to change html button's text with php and javascript but it doesn't give errors and i don't know what is wrong.

My code that i am trying to get working.

At start of the file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["LOGGED"] = "Log in";
?>
```

Then comes the button code

```
<button class='button' id='login'>button</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      <?php 
          echo "var msg = '" .$_SESSION["LOGGED"] . "'"; 
      ?>

      document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = msg;
  </script>
```

What is wrong? The text just doesn't change.

Edit: The 2 sciprts php part crashes the script? It says unexpected token <. Removed the php part and putted to .innerHTML = "test"; and the button changed to test. So it should be somewhere at the php part?

Comment: When you open the console, can you see that new value is being set to msg?

Comment: Tested your code just now works fine for me.

Comment: No, it says unexpected token '<'. It is when the <?php starts where is the javascript.

Comment: I think that is your problem then.  Do you have php setup?

Comment: I can not be 100% sure but i downloaded xampp for mac and putted my files into htdocs. I think it should work. Any simple test to see php working? Edit: Did phpinfo, shows the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your file a .php file and does the php work correctly?

try testing your php  by putting

```
<?php echo "Hello world!"; ?>
```

at the top of your page :)

Comment: It is html file where is php. Isn't php files supposed to be php only? Well, you solved the problem. It was html file.

Comment: No, only the code between <? and ?> will be parsed as php. the rest can be just plain html (or javascript or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `<button>` tag,

```
document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = msg;
```

should work.

But if you're using `<input type="button">`, then you will have to use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById('login').value = msg;
```

EDIT: Try this...

```
<script>
    var msg = <?php echo $_SESSION["LOGGED"]; ?>; //Don't forget the extra semicolon!
    document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = msg;
</script>
```

Comment: Just checked, i have the right way. Check my edit, updated information. Thanks for the try.